# Unable to build app bundle (.aab) in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, apk, android-app-bundle

I want to make an app bundle to upload app to the play store. But I have a problem when I create an app bundle, I get results as apk. I run this syntax:

`cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --packageType=bundle`

but the result of the syntax is

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
45 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 44 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        E:\project\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk
```

I use Cordova version `10.0.0` and android version `android 7.1.4`

Please help me, why can't I build an app bundle(.aab)?

Comment: cordova starts respecting the `--packageType=bundle` arg starting with cordova-android 8.x.x

Answer (score 12):

to build an App bundle, first build and generate your apk with

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Then go into platforms/android folder and generate your bundle with gradlew using the following command

```
cd platforms/android && ./gradlew bundle
```

the bundle file can be found at the following folder

```
platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release
```

also according to Google 'Starting August 2021, new apps will be required to target API level 30'. You should target sdk version 30 and can easily do that by adding android-targetSdkVersion in your config.xml

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
```

Comment: thanks for reply sir, get error on run ```cd platforms/android && ./gradlew bundle```

this result error
```Task 'bundle' is ambiguous in root project 'android'. Candidates are: 'bundleAppClassesDebug', 'bundleAppClassesDebugAndroidTest', 'bundleAppClassesDebugUnitTest', 'bundleAppClassesRelease', 'bundleAppClassesReleaseUnitTest', 'bundleDebug', 'bundleRelease'.
```

Comment: not create file on ```platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release``` just create apk

Comment: @MRZRasyaGaming replace `./gradlew bundle` with `./gradlew bundleRelease`

Answer (score 0):

firstly, create a `build.json` file that contains config about your keystore. see this doc https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#using-buildjson

then use this command to build your app

```
cordova build android --release --buildConfig=build.json
```